# export interface and a class extend Component/PureComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Im learning some react and react native and have a question about a following

```
export interface A {
  data: books;
  actions: actions;
  status: statusReport;
}

class myClass extends PureComponent<A> {
}
```

Can someone explain what is the meaning when we are doing `export interface A` and then we are doing `<A>` for `myClass` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The interface declaration is defining a type.** Any object or class that implements `A` must have the characteristics that type `A` defines; so, it must have three properties: `data`, `actions`, and `status`.

```
let a: A = {

    // required
    data: {},
    actions: {},
    status: {}, 

    // illegal
    next: {},
};
```

**`PureComponent<A>` is defining a react component with `props` of type `A`.** That means `props` has three properties: `data`, `actions`, and `status`.

**For more information** see the [type definitions here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/028e63335139a3a0639b538a6aab9fe3fb7cfa38/types/react/index.d.ts). The `PureComponent` class extends the `Component` class, and the `Component` class has a constructor that receives `props`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I cant find any syntax like PureComponent<A> in react or react native. AFAIK any object or class implements A, should we use keyword `implement`

Comment: `PureComponent` is a class not an interface. Generally speaking, we extend classes and implement interfaces. The reason that you cannot find any documentation about `<A>` in the React documentation is that React is written in JavaScript, whereas the `<A>` syntax is TypeScript. The official docs tend only to include the JavaScript bits.